# Setting CORS headers do not solve my CORS problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, heroku, cors

I'm trying to call an endpoint(`POST` `https://target-endpoint.com/authentication`) from another origin(`https://origin.com`) with below header settings, but CORS error has remain raised.

Is there any mistake in my settings?

`authentications_controller.rb`

```
def create
  response.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = 'https://origin.com'
  // some impl
end
```

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post :authentication, to: "authentications#create", via: :options
end
```

error in chrome console

```
Access to fetch at 'https://target-endpoint.com/authentication' from origin 'https://origin.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

error in chrome network tab
[image]

If you have any idea, please let me know.
Thanks,

---

other conds.

- heroku, with stack 18
- ruby 2.6.4
- rails 6.0.4.8

Comment: You did not show your CORS setup here. This would generally be set in an initializer. [This guide](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/rails-cors-guide/) is pretty highlevel but explanatory enough for a simple configuration. Otherwise take a look at the [Docs](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

Comment: Please don't add fake "tags" to your title. Just use the real tags that Stack Overflow provides. The fact that this question title is rejected without the "【Rails】" bit is a good sign that it needs improvement. As the automated suggestion says, "Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: Rather than implementing CORS "manually" (which is error-prone), use a proven CORS middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before browsers make a cross-origin POST request, they first perform a so called CORS-preflight request to make sure that the target of the POST allows the request.

For that, browsers make an `OPTIONS` request to the URL and check the CORS headers of the response. Only if the respone headers of this preflight request indicate that the request is allowed, browsers will perform the actual `POST` request.

For you, that means that your `create` action (for the `POST` request) won't receive a request unless you also reply to an `OPTIONS` request first.

While you could implement this "by hand", it is usually a much better idea to use existing CORS implementation such as the [`rack-cors` gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).